# ExactTarget - ComplexFilterPart - Multiple Exclude ListIDs

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Using the ExactTarget API, can you create a ComplexFilterPart and include a SimpleFilterPart that contains multiple ListIDs to exclude?  It seems that there should be a NOTIN SimpleOperators option however, I only see an IN SimpleOperators option.

Thanks.